# How to obtain the implementation address from an upgradeable proxy smart contract?

Tags: contract-invocation, addresses, contract-upgrading

Is there any way to **externally** obtain the current implementation address of a proxy that doesn't involve interacting actively with it (e.g. calling a transfer or approve function, i.e. without using gas)?

Let's use for example the USDC ERC-20 token, which its upgradeable proxy smart contract's address is: [0xA0b8...eB48](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#code) and it's current contract implementation to which it delegates to with the fallback function is [0xb727...78a2](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb7277a6e95992041568d9391d09d0122023778a2#code).

Is it possible?